# Finding the nth term of a sequence involving a difference of the reciprocal of the triangular numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following sequence:
$0, \frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{5}, \frac{2}{3}$.

I have found that the differences between the terms can be found using the nth term:
$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}n^2+1.5n+1}$

However, I'm not sure how to use this to give the nth term for the original sequence - wondering whether it may have to be expressed as a geometric progression.

Answer (score 2):

Your recurrence is $a_{n}=a_{n-1}+\frac 2{n^2+3n+2}=a_{n-1}+\frac 2{(n+2)(n+1)}$l  Expand the fraction in partial fractions and the sum will telescope.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: double denominators and numerators in every other term, and write $0$ as $0/2$.